# error: PDF2DSC sentinel: Wrong type argument: arrayp, nil

Tags: errors, emacs, auctex, ghostscript

I am trying to get AUCTeX on Emacs to preview formulas but it doesn't seem to work and when I click preview, it produces the following error:

```
PDF2DSC sentinel: Wrong type argument: arrayp, nil
```

I have Emacs, AUCTeX and Ghostscript installed on a Windows 10 machine. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need Ghostscript in your `PATH`.  Easier is to use the binaries provided by TeXlive.  If you have `c:\path\to\texlive\2016\bin\win32` in your `PATH`, Emacs should find and use everything it needs there.